# Cajero Con Archivo TXT en java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente codigo :

```
    String prueba;
    String cad;
    FileReader f=new FileReader("cuentas.txt");
    BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(f);

    while((cad=b.readLine())!=null){
    String parts[]=cad.split(";");

    prueba = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese numero de cuenta");

    if(prueba.equals(parts[0])){
        System.out.println("Saldo es: "+parts[1]);
        break;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("error");
        break;
        }

    }
```

Y el siguiente archivo de txt

> ## Numero Cuenta,Dolares
>
> 1000001;400
>   1000002;200
>   1000004;500

Quisiera saber ¿como puedo sacar las demás posiciones de mi arreglo? ya que solo puedo sacar la posición [0] y [1] o ¿como crear el array para poder sacar las posiciones y poder hacer las comparaciones ?

Comment: ¿A que llamas demas posiciones?

Comment: Entiendo lo que preguntas porque tu compañero de clase ha preguntado lo mismo. El primer split que debes hacer es de " " para separar las cuentas entre sí. Luego lo harás con ";" para separar cuentas de saldos

Comment: osea que debo de crear un nuevo while ? donde usar el otro split ??